# Как вернуть первый промис из полифила Promise.race()?

Tags: javascript, promise

Всем привет,  делаю полифил Promise.race().

Но не могу понять, почему мой вариант не нравится тестам.

На скрине ответ оригинального race (тесты проходит) и моего (тесты не проходит, но выглядит так же).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4svVt.png)

```
// ДАНО
const firstPromise = new Promise((resolve) =>
  setTimeout(() => resolve(5000), 5000)
);

const secondPromise = new Promise((resolve) =>
  setTimeout(() => resolve(4000), 4000)
);

const thirdPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
  setTimeout(() => resolve(2000), 2000)
);

// оригинал для сверки ответа
function promiseOriginRace (promises) {
  return Promise.race(promises)
}

console.log('ответ оригинального race', promiseOriginRace([firstPromise, secondPromise, thirdPromise]));


//мой полифил
function promiseRace(promises) {

  // массив для записи всех результатов
  let answerArr = []

  // запускаем все промисы и записываем результаты в массив
  promises.forEach(pr =>
    pr.then((result) => {
      answerArr.push(pr)
    }).catch((e) => {
      answerArr.push(pr)
    })
  )

  // после завершения всех или отклонения первого 
  // возвращаем первый результат из массива
  return Promise.all(promises).then((r) => {
    console.log('лог до возврата', answerArr[0]);
    return answerArr[0];
  })
}

console.log('мой ответ', promiseRace([firstPromise, secondPromise, thirdPromise]));
```

Comment: так полифин или полифил? определитесь, пожалуйста, нажав [edit]

Comment: Как минимум, оригинальный `race` возвращает результат через 2 секунды, а Ваша версия - через 5. Если в `firstPromise` вместо 5000 будет 50000000, то ждать придётся долговато.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По [описанию](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race), `race` должен завершаться когда завершится первый.

В твоем примере, с помощью [`all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) идет ожидание **всех** переданных `Promise`.

Для решения можно воспользоваться тем, что `Promise` может поменять свое состояние только один раз, таким образом для реализации `race`, достаточно создать новый `Promise`, которые разрешится либо отменится после любого из переданных:

```js
// ДАНО
const firstPromise = new Promise((resolve) =>
  setTimeout(() => resolve(5000), 5000)
);

const secondPromise = new Promise((resolve) =>
  setTimeout(() => resolve(4000), 4000)
);

const thirdPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
  setTimeout(() => resolve(2000), 2000)
);

// оригинал для сверки ответа
function promiseOriginRace(promises) {
  return Promise.race(promises)
}

promiseOriginRace([firstPromise, secondPromise, thirdPromise]).then(r => console.log('ответ оригинального race', r));


//мой полифил
function promiseRace(promises) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => promises.forEach(p => p.then(resolve, reject)))
}

promiseRace([firstPromise, secondPromise, thirdPromise]).then(r => console.log('ответ полифила race', r));
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!