# Как сделать функцию, которая принимает массив промисов и возвращает результат того, который завершился первым?

Tags: javascript

Всем здравствуйте, необходимо написать функцию, которая принимает массив промисов и возвращает результат того, который завершился первым. Если первый промис выдал ошибку - то вернуть ее.
Пример:

```js
const firstPromise = new Promise((resolve) =>
  setTimeout(() => resolve(300), 300)
);
 
const secondPromise = new Promise((resolve) =>
  setTimeout(() => resolve(200), 200)
);
 
const thirdPromise = new Promise((resolve) =>
  setTimeout(() => resolve(100), 100)
);
 
promiseRace([firstPromise, secondPromise, thirdPromise]); // 100
```

Мой код:

```js
function promiseRace(promises) {
  if (promises.length === 0) return Promise.resolve([]);
  const copy = [...promises]; 
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let count = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < promises.length; i++) {
      promises[i].then(res => {
        copy[i] = res;
        if (++count === promises.length) resolve(copy);
      }).catch(err => reject(err));
    }
  });
}
```

Не проходит один тест: "должна возвращать результат первого выполнившегося промиса", что надо исправить?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1456297

Comment: `Promise.race()` все так и делает... https://learn.javascript.ru/promise-api#promise-race

Comment: @andreymal, спасибо!

Comment: @ksa, спасибо !

Answer (score 0):

Такое?

```js
const firstPromise = new Promise((resolve) =>
  setTimeout(() => resolve(300), 300)
);
 
const secondPromise = new Promise((resolve) =>
  setTimeout(() => resolve(200), 200)
);
 
const thirdPromise = new Promise((resolve) =>
  setTimeout(() => resolve(100), 100)
);
 
promiseRace([firstPromise, secondPromise, thirdPromise])
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(err => console.log('Ошибка', err))

//
function promiseRace(arr = []) {
  if (!arr.length) return Promise.resolve(null)
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      arr[i]
        .then(resolve)
        .catch(reject)
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Какая разница межу вашим кодом и [кодом @Grundy](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1456297/#1456315)?

Comment: @ΝNL993. в моем используется метод массива [`.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) , а тут обычный цикл. Плюс у меня `reject` указывается в `then`, а здесь в `catch`, конкретно в этом случае разницы не будет, хотя иногда может быть

Comment: @Grundy про цикл немного натянуто, разница близка к нулевой, а вот `catch` я и вправду не заметил.

Comment: @ΝNL993 и еще одно, на самом деле существенное, отличие - работа с пустым массивом.